# How to split array and use several requests.get in parallel with python?

Tags: python

My originale requeste is:

```
def get_foo_by_bars(authorisation_token: str, bar_ids: list):
    r = requests.get(BASE_URL + "/api/v1/foo/bar",
                 params={"bar_ids": bar_ids, "data_type": "Float"},
                 headers={"Authorization": authorisation_token})
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()["data"]["data"]
```

My problem is bar_ids size contain more 80 element so my url size is more 2048 char. I want to be able to launch several requests in parallel with for example 10 bar_id then do a merge of the x responses at the end before the `return`.

Answer (score 0):

That might be possible via [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) + [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/). Unfortunatly I have no API to test this against right now, so the following code might have some issues, but should at least give you an idea:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

# async function to get json result for subset of bar_ids
async def get(session, **kwargs):
    try:
        async with session.get(**kwargs) as response:
            await response.read()
            if response.status == 200:
                return await response.json()
            return {}
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"ERROR:\n{kwargs}\n{exc}")
        return {}

# async function to split bar_ids into subsets, get their result and join them to the final result
async def main(bar_ids, package_size):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        packaged_kwargs = [{
                "url": BASE_URL + "/api/v1/foo/bar",
                "params": {"bar_ids": bar_ids[i:i + package_size], "data_type": "Float"},
                "headers": {"Authorization": AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN},
            } for i in range(0, len(bar_ids), package_size)]
        json_list = await asyncio.gather(*[get(session, **kwargs) for kwargs in packaged_kwargs])
    result = {key: value for json_dict in json_list for key, value in json_dict.items()}
    print(result)

# parameters
BASE_URL = "https://www.google.com"
AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN = "823ljf9823puj8ö3"
bar_ids = list(range(100))
package_size = 10

# run
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())  # only required for windows
asyncio.run(main(bar_ids,package_size))
```